# What safety precaution measures should be taken if I want to embed my web app to a third party native app(android ios)?

Tags: android, ios, security, web

We have a web app(register/login、bind credit card、buy financial product...). Is it safe to embed this web app to a third party native apps(ios/android webview) for promotion? If not what precaution measure should I take?

- Any related Apple Store/Google Play review policy should I notice?
- What kind of web security problem should I concern? i.e. User input action spying by third party native app.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#physical-goods-and-services

Comment: look you can't add deny apple for any payment/transaction related operation. If your app does so then you can't.

Comment: I'm not going to use IAP @nspavlo

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I don't really understand

Comment: does your app have any transaction feature or money payment functionality?